# Sonata type collection delete row triggers constraints validation

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

I have a problem with sonata admin, specifically in a type collection field. Here's the scenario:

I have an entity called "Group" with a one to many relationship to the entity "Member"

In sonata admin I set up the admin classes for the 2 entities.

In the "Group admin" i create a collection type with the Member entity  this way

```
->add('members', 'sonata_type_collection', [
    'by_reference'          => false,
    'label'                 => 'Members',
    'type_options'          => ['delete' => true],
    'btn_add'               => "Add Member",
    'required'              => false,
    'constraints'           => $validation['members'],
],
[
    'edit'              => 'inline',
    'inline'            => 'table'
])
```

The member entity has 4 fields, one of which is required.

```
->add('firstName', TextType::class, [
    'label'         => 'First Name'
    'constraints'   => [
        new NotBlank(['message' => 'Please enter the name.']),
    ]
])
```

If I click the "Add Member" button in the edit view, it adds a new row as expected.
At that point, if I change my mind and decide to delete the newly added record, without adding the name, on save it's returning a validation error telling me 'Please enter the name.' on the field.

Shouldn't the delete action have priority over validation?

Comment: Yes validation have priority..... May be you need to add delete button for each member... After delete you need to save the rest members..

Comment: There is not delete button. The delete option is rendered as a checkbox. This is a sonata admin widget.

Comment: Having this problem as well i think an issue should be opened on SonataAdminBundle about that

Comment: I raised he issue on SonataAdminBundle. https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/4348

Answer (score 0):

I made a pull request that fixed this issue and it has been merged in 3.x.

Now when you click a delete checkbox the related fields are disabled so you don't have any problem when submitting your form.

https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/pull/4358

Comment: Do you have an example of use? I found that pull but don't know how to use it

Comment: As you can see from the PR it has been meged then reverted as it was not the proper fix.sorry